# Best method for parallel log aggregation

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, scala, future

My program needs to analyze a bunch of log files daily which are generated on a hourly basis from each application server.

So if I have 2 app servers I will be processing 48 files (24 files * 2 app servers).

file sizes range 100-300 mb. Each line in every file is a log entry which is of the format

**[identifier]-[number of pieces]-[piece]-[part of log]**

for example

```
xxx-3-1-ABC
xxx-3-2-ABC
xxx-3-3-ABC
```

These can be distributed over the 48 files which I mentioned, I need to merge these logs like so

```
xxx-PAIR-ABCABCABC
```

My implementation uses a thread pool to read through files in parallel and then aggregate them using a ConcurrentHashMap

I define a class LogEvent.scala

```
class LogEvent (val id: String, val total: Int, var piece: Int, val json: String) {

  var additions: Long = 0
  val pieces = new Array[String](total)
  addPiece(json)


  private def addPiece (json: String): Unit = {
    pieces(piece) = json
    additions += 1
  }

  def isDone: Boolean = {
    additions == total
  }


  def add (slot: Int, json: String): Unit = {
    piece = slot
    addPiece(json)
  }
```

The main processing happens over multiple threads and the code is something on the lines of

```
//For each file
val logEventMap = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, LogEvent]().asScala
Future {
          Source.fromInputStream(gis(file)).getLines().foreach {
            line =>

                  //Extract the id part of the line
                  val idPart: String = IDPartExtractor(line)
                  //Split line on '-'
                  val split: Array[String] = idPart.split("-")



                    val id: String = split(0) + "-" + split(1)
                    val logpart: String = JsonPartExtractor(line)
                    val total = split(2) toInt
                    val piece = split(3) toInt

                    def slot: Int = {
                      piece match {
                        case x if x - 1 < 0 => 0
                        case _ => piece - 1
                      }
                    }

                    def writeLogEvent (logEvent: LogEvent): Unit = {
                      if (logEvent.isDone) {
                        //write to buffer
                        val toWrite = id + "-PAIR-" + logEvent.pieces.mkString("")
                        logEventMap.remove(logEvent.id)
                        writer.writeLine(toWrite)
                      }
                    }

                    //The LOCK
                    appendLock {
                      if (!logEventMap.contains(id)) {
                        val logEvent = new LogEvent(id, total, slot, jsonPart)
                        logEventMap.put(id, logEvent)
                        //writeLogEventToFile()
                      }
                      else {
                        val logEvent = logEventMap.get(id).get
                        logEvent.add(slot, jsonPart)
                        writeLogEvent(logEvent)

                      }
                    } 
                }
          }
```

The main thread blocks till all the futures complete

Using this approach I have been able to cut the processing time from an hour+ to around 7-8 minutes.

My questions are as follows -

1. Can this be done in a better way, I am reading multiple files using different threads and I need to lock at the block where the aggregation happens, are there better ways of doing this?
2. The Map grows very fast in memory, any suggestions for off heap storage for such a use case
3. Any other feedback.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe a good idea will be to use some distributed DB like Cassandra, Riak, MongoDb etc? Then on each node you can create a scheduled bean which will be responsible for getting the log data and put then inside the db. From the outside of the cluster you could use another client of the distributed db which will be responsible for copy those logs on your machine. That's the common use case of distributed db's.

Comment: I am skeptical about using a distributed DB/ store because there is no need for any persistence, the only time I need to store data is when the pieces are being merged. Maybe a pure memory store like Redis would do? any thoughts

Answer (score 1):

A common way to do this is to sort each file and then merge the sorted files. The result is a single file that has the individual items in the order that you want them. Your program then just needs to do a single pass through the file, combining adjacent matching items.

This has some very attractive benefits:

1. The sort/merge is done by standard tools that you don't have to write
2. Your aggregator program is very simple. Or, there might even be a standard tool that will do it.
3. Memory requirements are lessened. The sort/merge programs know how to manage memory, and your aggregation program's memory requirements are minimal.

There are, of course some drawbacks. You'll use more disk space and the process will be somewhat slower due to the I/O cost.

When I'm faced with something like this, I almost always go with using the standard tools and a simple aggregator program. The increased performance I get from a custom program just doesn't justify the time it takes to develop the thing.

Comment: That approach would certainly be slow, I am generating merged files upto 14 GB in some instances,
Also could you point me towards some tools that you mentioned

Comment: @winash: Standard tools like the GNU Tools sort, which will sort and merge. Windows comes with a sort program, but I wouldn't recommend it as anything but a toy. And it won't merge anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For this sort of thing, if you can, use [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com), if not, copy what it does which is index the log files for aggregation on demand at a later point.

For off heap storage, look at distributed caches - Hazelcast or Coherence.  Both support provide `java.util.Map` implementations that are stored over multiple JVMs.

Comment: Splunk is a paid tool and I think it would be an overkill for this.

Comment: This is exactly what Splunk is meant for - their charging model is based on the volume of data being indexed so you'll pay for what you use.